# Finite many primes for every positive integer $b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial, prime-factorization

Consider the function $$f(a,b):=\sum_{j=0}^a (bj)!=1+b!+(2b)!+\cdots +(ab)!$$

> Given a positive integer $b$ , are there always only a finite number of positive integers $a$ such that $f(a,b)$ is prime ?

Idea :

To show that we only have finite many prime numbers, we only have to find a prime $p$ and a positive integer $a$ such that $p<ab$ and $p\mid f(a,b)$. In this case we have the same prime factor $p$ for every larger $a$ hence only finite many primes.

However, for some positive integers $b$ , I could not find such a prime $p$ and a suitable $a$, for example for $b=15$ and $b=19$. Can we expect only finite many primes also in those cases ? Or does even a pair $(a,p)$ exist for every positive integer $b$ ?

Comment: What is the source of this question, please?

Comment: Well, definitely there are values of $b$ for which $f(a,b)$ is not a prime for any $a$. Indeed, if $p>3$ is a prime and $b=p-1$, by Wilson's Theorem we know that $$(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}$$ thus $p\mid f(a,b)$ for any $a\geq 1$.

Comment: WHAT IS THE SOURCE OF THIS QUESTION, PLEASE?

Comment: This function is my invention. I never saw it before. It generalizes the factorial numbers $n!+1$ which have been checked for primality upto a very high level.